# Divide k-v data across cluster evenly?

Tags: distributed-computing, key-value-store

I've been using leveldb on a single server to store large amounts of data. I have calculated that dividing the database across multiple machines in a cluster with lower ram and lower disk size is going to give us a better cost/benefit ratio.

Is there a persistent key-value database that I can use to distribute the data evenly across a cluster that lets me query it for lexically ordered key ranges?

Edit:

By "distributed evenly" I don't mean "repllication". I mean the cluster is treated as a single machine and total memory space is increased by every machine that enters the cluster.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't heard of a distributed key-value stores that allows for range queries, but you can try a map-reducible data store like Riak.  It's more document based, but you should be able to query it the way you want, and it's designed to scale up to many nodes cleanly.

Answer (score 0):

Riak is a key-value store that allows you to store any type of binary data, not just documents, and will automatically distribute and manage replicas of your data across a cluster. LevelDB is one of the supported storage engines, and allows you to define secondary indexes that can be used in exact match or range queries. The key of stored objects is made available for secondary index querying through an [automatically provided $key index](http://docs.basho.com/riak/latest/ops/advanced/configs/secondary-index/#Index-Lookups), which will allow you to run range queries based on the object key.